# FOR Loop Variable Arithmetic - Batch Scripting

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, integer-arithmetic

So I'm working on a final project for one of my classes, and the goal is basically to have the user input an initial investment, and the number of years the value will depreciate...it depreciates by a constant value which is determined by the investment divided by the number of years.

In the for loop, it should subtract the 'annual' from the 'bookvalue' and print out the new bookvalue for each year...the math itself works correctly (I believe?) because if I echo the values outside my for loop they are what they should be, but with the echo statement inside the for loop I don't get what I need it to output (the bookvalue doesn't change inside the loop).

Not really sure where to go with this, and Google hasn't done me very well yet. Thanks for any help that can be given!

```
@ECHO OFF
:HEADER  
REM Program : final_q8.bat
REM Author :
REM Date : 
REM Purpose : if statement integer sort 
REM ----------------------------------------------- 

:START
CLS

SET /P INVEST="Please enter the initial investment amount: "
SET /P YEARS="Please enter the # of years the machine will be depreciated: "
SET /A ANNUAL=INVEST/YEARS

SET BOOKVALUE=%INVEST%

ECHO YEAR    ANNUAL DEPRECIATION    BOOK VALUE

FOR /L %%C IN (1, 1, %YEARS%) DO (
    SET /A BOOKVALUE=BOOKVALUE-ANNUAL
    ECHO  %%C       %ANNUAL%                   %BOOKVALUE%
)

PAUSE 
:END 
:: Exit and return an errorcode of 0 
EXIT /B 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling `Delayed expansion`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
...
```

Then use exclamation mark inside `For` loop

```
FOR /L %%C IN (1, 1, %YEARS%) DO (
 SET /A BOOKVALUE=BOOKVALUE-ANNUAL
 ECHO  %%C       !ANNUAL!                   !BOOKVALUE!
)
```